# I am calling a restful web service and get this error message: System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type

Tags: c#

I am calling a restful web service from ios application (ipad) and get this error message: System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type. When it reached this line: System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage  response = await client.GetAsync(RestUrl).

Here's the code:

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetSSRListAsync() 
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var RestUrl = "http://10.50.42.51:2018/SiteSafetyService.svc/GetSSRList";
    //var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, string.Empty));
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage  response = await client.GetAsync(RestUrl);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(content);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: I am using the most current version of xamarin on both MAc and PC

Comment: If this is your actual code:  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage  respons`enter code here`e = await client.GetAsync(RestUrl); remove the 'enter code here'

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full exception detail.

Comment: The full exception is: System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type.I believe it's because of the Newtonsoft.Json dll that I'm using.

Comment: There will be much more detail than that.